# Automated network builder

Tags: network-analyst

Is there a way to create a network based on road elevations , to build a sewer/Strom drain network . The idea is to draw a polyline from higher elevation to lower elevation automatically.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Which GIS software are you using?  Please [edit] your question to include this and any additional info.  Do you already have a Sewer/Storm network, or are you wanting to construct that completely?